# How to retrieve validator for an existing MongoDB collection using Java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

Using the MongoDB Java driver I would like to retrieve a [validator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) defined for a collection. In mongo Shell this can be easily achieved by running `db.getCollectionInfos({name: "MyTestCollection"})[0].options.validator;` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318188/add-new-validator-to-existing-collection).

What I miss is a similar method on the [MongoDatabase](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/com/mongodb/client/MongoDatabase.html) class or a [Database Command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/) I can run with the `MongoDatabase.runCommand(...)` method.

What do I miss? How to retrieve that information in Java?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Yes, just answered my own question. Sorry for not doing it earlier.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I managed to retrieve the schema in question:

```
...
MongoDbJsonSchemaRetriever(MongoDatabase database) {
    this.database = database;
}

Document retrieveJsonSchema(String collectionName) {
    Document collection = database.listCollections().filter(byName(collectionName)).first();
    return readJsonSchema(collection);
}

private Bson byName(String collectionName) {
    return Filters.eq("name", collectionName);
}

private static Document readJsonSchema(Document collection) {
    return collection.get("options", EMPTY).get("validator", EMPTY).get("$jsonSchema", EMPTY);
}
```

Usage is straightforward:

```
new MongoDbJsonSchemaRetriever(yourDatabase).retrieveJsonSchema(yourCollectionName)
```

You will retrieve either the schema or an empty document if no schema is defined/found.

Let me know if you have found a better way.